# Combinatorial problem on processing all subsets according to a given function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve [this problem.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/manasa-and-pizza/problem) Given a set $S$, consider the set $T$ of all subsets of $S$. For each element, $X$ in $T$ define quantity:

$$b_i =|\sum X - \sum \bar{X}|$$

where $\sum X$ denotes the sum of elements of set $X$ and $\bar{X}$ is the complement of $X$ with respect to $S$. Further, consider a function $F$ defined as $F(0) = 1, F(1) = 3$, $F(n) = 6F(n-1)-F(n-2)$. We are required to find the value of $\sum F(b_i)$. Here $b_i$s corresponding to each $X$ in $T$ must be taken into account. This sum must be calculated modulo $10^9 + 7$.

I would like to say that the constraints here are $|S| \leq 5100$ and an element of $S$ is a positive integer which can be as large as $10^{15}$. Hence, a brute force approach is ruled out.

Next, I noticed that we must be able to calculate $F(n) \mod 10^9 + 7$ for large $n$. Indeed, if $S = \{10^{15}\}$ then the required answer should be $2F(10^{15}) \mod 10^9 + 7$. This number is impossible to calculate using the recurrence relation in a reasonable amount of time (1-2s).

I therefore tried to compute the period of the sequence $F(n) \mod 10^9 + 7$, but was not able to do so using a computer program (the program did not terminate). So, if such a period exists then it is too large to be helpful in computation anyway. I'm stuck and have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: You might make use of $$F(n) = \frac{(3+2\sqrt 2)^n + (3-2\sqrt 2)^n}2$$ It might also be useful that $(3+2\sqrt 2)(3-2\sqrt 2) = 1$.

Comment: Computing such a recurrence can be done using matrix exponentiation in logarithmic time.
You can read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)